# How do I define a "Callable" type that corresponds to a function with variable arguments?

Tags: python, types

I like to make sure that I have accurate type hints, but how can I write the type of this function using `typing.Callable`?

```
def f(x: int, *args, **kwargs): 
    pass
```

e.g.

```
Callable[[int, ?????], None]
```

Answer (score 1):

Paraphrasing from the documentation of [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

You can use `Callable[[Arg1Type, Arg2Type], ReturnType]` to specify the input arguments and the `ReturnType`.

If the types of the input arguments are not known, you could use the ellipsis notation instead: `Callable[..., ReturnType].`

Comment: Yup, I read the docs, and I tried ``Callable[[int, ...], None]`` and it doesn't work. ``Callable[..., None]`` is not quite what I wanted as it does not specify the type of the first argument.